# Differentiable in normed vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I am not sure if i proved this right.

Let $X$ and all $Y_i$ be normed Vector spaces and $Y_i = Y_1 \times... \times Y_n$ .

$\pi _i$ is the canonical projection of $Y$ to $Y_i$

Show for all $a \in X, k\in \mathbb N\quad \text{&} \quad f:X \longrightarrow Y $

$$\text{f is $k$-times differentiable in a} \Longleftrightarrow  \pi_i \circ f  \quad \text{is $k$-times differentiable in a for all $i$} $$

"$\Longrightarrow $" is easy

"$\Longleftarrow$" $\pi_i \circ f $ k-times differentiable $\Rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{i} f^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(y_i)) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i}\pi_i^{-1}(y_i)) = f^{-1}(Y) = X \Rightarrow f \quad \text{k-times differentiable}$

Comment: How does $\bigcup\limits_{i} f^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(y_i)) = f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i}\pi_i^{-1}(y_i)) = f^{-1}(Y) = X $  prove $f$ is k-times differentiable ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By induction on $k$, WLOG you may assume $k=1$. Let $a \in X$ and the Linear map $g_i \in L(X, Y_{i} )$ is derivative of $\pi_i \circ f : X \to Y_i$ at point $x=a,$

Now show that the linear map $T(x) = (g_1 (x), g_2 (x), ..., g_n(x)) \in L(X, Y) $ is the derivative of $f$ at point $x=a$